# Cannot create new AWS account in newly created AWS organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

I am receiving the following [image: Error image] when I try to add new AWS accounts to my newly created organization. Any thoughts on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: I also faced this issue and filled a ticket to AWS Support, they solved it.

Comment: Thank you. It's very bad that a huge company like AWS cannot solve this problem. I've found people complaining about it in March and still they didn't solved the problem.

Comment: I created a ticket to the support and they solved it. Thank God!

Comment: This happend to me couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your account has a complete billing profile, including payment information. If that is the case, and you are still having issues, AWS support will be able to help you identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If this error occurs, wait for few minutes and retry. If it comes again contact AWS support. They will fix the issue mostly in 24hours time.

Comment: They did not fixed in 24 hours, but they fixed it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is a clear message on the top, that your organization is in initialization status. Because of that you should wait until it's done initializing (in some cases it could take about an hour) and try again. AWS Documentation states ([see step #7. Create](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_create.html)), that

> If you get an error that indicates that you can't add an account
>   because your organization is still initializing, wait one hour and try
>   again.

Therefore there is no need to contact a support for this kind of problems.